# angularjs toggle $stateProvider views based on viewport

Tags: angularjs

I have a view with 3 nested views, when the viewport is less than 768 I want to hide 2 of the 3 nested views and toggle between the three.  What is the best method to toggle nested views with $stateProvider, I've been looking around but getting mixed answers.

I am using jade/coffeescript.

```
.state 'messages',
  url: '/messages',
  views:
    '':
      templateUrl: 'views/messages.html',
      controller: 'MessagesCtrl'
    'ticketList@messages':
      templateUrl: 'views/messages/list.html'
    'ticketComments@messages' :
      templateUrl: '/views/messages/comments.html'
    'ticketDetail@messages' :
      templateUrl: '/views/messages/detail.html'
```

and the main view:

```
div(ui-view="ticketList")

div(ui-view="ticketComments")

div(ui-view="ticketDetail")
```

Comment: Use CSS and media queries.